# Managed Release to Production marked 'Superseded' after releasing open beta

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have a release in Managed Release awaiting to be manually published (v1.0.19). I also have a beta that I released to open Testers (v1.0.20). However now when I view the pending Production release it shows 'Superseded'.

I have paused and removed all testers from the open testing track. However since Timed Publishing is active it is still showing beta (1.0.20) under changes ready to publish.

Will this affect my production release when I select Publish in the publishing overview?

Answer (score 2):

Pausing the beta branch reverted the release from superseded to ready to publish.